# Magento 2. Catalog product edit save button not working

Tags: magento2, adminform, save, product-edit

`admin/catalog/product/save` button is not working anymore.

I'm unable to `edit/save` product.

- **No** output whatsoever in `var/log/*`
- **No** output whatsoever in `browser console`
- **No** activity in `browser network tab`
- **No** custom module messing with the form.

Any tips on further debugging this?

Answer (score 2):

Check your advanced inventory information / Maximum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart
This field must be either empty, or have a value greater than 0.
another option is to tick the checkbox "Use Config Settings", and make sure the configuration is set correctly.

Answer (score 0):

As per magento community answer https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Admin-Configuration/Product-Save-button-is-not-working/m-p/134709#M2739

Make sure to check "Advanced Pricing" after clicking the link under Price, if all other attributes seems populated.

Answer (score 0):

had the same tricky bug. No visual feedback when clicked save. I had to expand the "advanced inventory" by clicking the link. Then I could see the error in the new overlay window. 
Thanks again, magento :/
solution found here: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/22274#issuecomment-482097350